# ¿Como crear el edit y delete en un crud de MVC, si no funciona el actionresult del controller?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework, crud

soy estudiante de inacap, y estoy haciendo una aplicación en asp.net con MVC 5 y entity framework, soy aún principiante en esto del lenguaje C#, acabo de crear mi primer crud de una tabla en sql llamada "Tienda" que tiene los siguientes atributos:

id_tienda int (autoincrementable en 1)
nombre nvarchar (50)
direccion nvarchar (50)
telefono int

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ningún campo permite nulos.

Luego, agregué el controlador y la vista para crear nueva tienda, puedo agregar nuevos registros con normalidad:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Todo bien, he intentado agregar el edit y delete como en todo crud normal, pero no he podido hacerlo, me aparece un error en mi aplicación.
Mi pregunta es,  ¿como puedo agregar la función para editar y eliminar en mi crud?

He tratado de seguir este tutorial, y sin éxito me sale error :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B52jljaYOWA

El código que puse para crear la función del edit en mi controller sería un código así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero cuando hago correr mi aplicación, sale un error, y al tipo le funcionó:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces, ¿como resuelvo esto?,
ah y por cierto, ya puse la vista de "Editar" en mi aplicación, me sería de gran ayuda si me ayudan, porque esto será para una evaluación importante, tengo hasta el 19 de julio para hacerla.

Comment: Hola para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, considera añadir tu código como texto, no como imagen

Answer (score 0):

El error dice que se espera un valor para el parámetro `id_tienda`. Asegúrate que el nombre del parámetro que envías se llama `id_tienda`. O cambia el nombre de `id_tienda` a `id` en la acción **Editar**.

Comment: ahora le puse int id y me sigue saliendo el error, que extraño, se supone que debería capturar el id de la fila de la tabla que quieres editar

Comment: ah, ya lo arreglé, lo que pasa es los Html.Actionlink tenían la asignación del id escrita en forma de comentario, y por eso no asignaba al id, ya funciona.